# Adding Completion to (interactive)

Tags: emacs, elisp, interactive

Is there any way to add my own completion to an `(interactive)` elisp function? Ideally, I'd like to pass it a list of strings that it would tab-complete from. I know that using `(interactive "D")`, `(interactive "F")` or `(interactive "b")` give you completion for directories, files and buffer-names respectively, but what about more general inputs?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The argument to `interactive` need not be a string; if it isn't, it's evaluated to get the list of arguments to pass to the function.  Therefore, you can do something like this:

```
(defun insert-foo-bar-or-baz (arg)
  (interactive
   (list
    (completing-read "Choose one: " '("foo" "bar" "baz"))))
  (insert arg))
```

Comment: /facepalm Now that I've seen an example, that comment in the `M-x apropos` entry for `interactive` makes perfect sense.

Comment: Don't work @lnaimathi you are not alone in the facepalming :) LOL

Comment: FTR: it turns out you can also pass strings unquoted, i.e. `(completing-read "Choose one: " '(foo bar baz))`, but the `type-of` of the `arg` will still be a `string`.